# SQLAlchemy model data isn't rendered in Jinja loop

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm trying to display a menu of items (like a lunch menu) but I can't get them to show up.  I added the items via a Flask-Admin page and checked the database to verify that the items actually exist so I know that's not my problem.  Why doesn't the menu item data render in the loop?

```
class MenuItems(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Float(6), unique=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(140))

@app.route('/menu')
def menu():
    menu_items = MenuItems.query.all()
    return render_template('menu.html', title="Dave's Bread - Menu",  menu_items=menu_items, user=current_user)
```

```html
{% for item in menu_items %}
  <td>
    <p><strong>{{ menu_items.name }}</strong></p>
    <p>{{ menu_items.description }}</p>
    <p>Price: {{ menu_items.price }}</p>
  </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're accessing properties on `menu_items` inside the loop.  You meant to use `item` to access the properties of each item.

Flask's Jinja environment skips rendering undefined values by default.  `menu_items` doesn't have a `description` attribute, so Jinja treats it as undefined.  You can make it more strict by using a different [undefined type](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#undefined-types).

```
from jinja2 import StrictUndefined
app.jinja_env.undefined = StrictUndefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't loop when you use first() because it's returning one item, rather than a list.

In the template you posted, you're looping over every item, but always referring to the list instead of the item (item instead of menu_items).